# javafx WebView setMember() before script

Tags: java, javascript, javafx

I am trying to set some javascript items on my page, but the items are getting set after the javascript runs on the page. So for example, I created a `Console.log()` method to display stuff in my java console for debugging purposes. But the items are getting set after the page code runs so the logging doesn't work (See second block of code). Is there a way for me to initiate the code before the javascript on the page runs?

So, here is how I am initiating the item in my Java application:

```java
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>(){
    if(newState.equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)){
        JSObject win = (JSObject)Browser.webEngine.executeScript("window");
        win.setMember("$js", new JavaScriptBinder());
        win.setMember("console", new JSConsole());
    }
}
```

Here is a javascript example:

```
<script>
    // This line doesn't work:
    console.log("Hello");

    element.addEventListener("click", function(){
        // This line does work:
        console.log("Hello from a click");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't letting the page finish loading before you run your javascript code. Consider linking your code to the `window.onload` method, e.g.

```
<script>
   function startup() {
      alert("The page has finished loading!  I'm ready to do stuff!");  
   }
   window.onload=startup;
</script>
```

Of course, this could cause a problem if any other parts of your code also try to attach themselves to `window.onload`. [I recommend reading this article if this is the case for you.](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Are_you_ready_for_this) FWIW, I also took the code sample above from that page.

Comment: The problem has to do with the java, not the javascript

Comment: This answer is correct. Ryan, you're having this issue because all your Java code is being executed after the JavaScript has been evaluated (that's what the stateProperty listener guarantees). So the first console.log doesn't work because when it's evaluated console hasn't been set yet. The second one works because it's not evaluated until the click event occurs (which is probably long after the Java code has been able to execute).